# Media query does not work on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using Chrome and [**Window Resizer**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh?hl=en) by ionut botizan v 1.9.1.2

I am using atom open source editor, although I initially created the page in phpstorm

**My problem**

I am able to click the window resize button and the page will resize upto ipad, when I try to resize mobile versions, 
high end windows phone, iphone and low end windows phone 
the browser window remains the size of the ipad coefficents `1024 x 768` and only some page elements will allow me to adjust its width, I can change other properties, i.e color,background etc. however the
width of header, banner and left_right_content,wont budge, adjust in size
this also cause the effect of being able to scroll to the right

I have tried other sites i have made and the plugin works fine, and I have also tested a live website, and that seems to work, theres is something in this code stopping resizing, maybe some one will notice where something I missed, any help welcome

```
        <head>

        <meta charset= "utf-8">
            <meta name="descripton" content="kids at play"/>

            <meta name= "keywords" content="kids, club, play, learn"/>

    <meta name="robots" content=index,follow/>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
     <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">

    <base href="http://localhost/Kids Club/Kids_Club.html"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Kids_Club.css" type="text/css"/>

        <title>html_5</title>

                </head>

    <body>

        <div id="wrapper">

          <div id="header"><img id ="img_header" src="jpg/kids_club_header.jpg" alt="kids club"/>

          </div>


          <nav>
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Playgroups</a>
                      <ul>
                          <li><a href="#">Under Fives</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Under Tens</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">The Teens</a>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Play & Learn</a>
                      <ul>
                          <li><a href="#">Field Trips</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Tutor Groups</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
              </ul>
          </nav>

          <div id="banner"><img id ="img_banner" src="jpg/kids.jpg" alt="kids"/>


          </div>
          <div id="left_col_content">

              <h2 class="top_title">Bring out the tiger in you</h2>
              <h3 class="top_title">Activities for the Under Fives and Tens</h3>
              <p>Is your little one sporty, and loves the challenge, then why not sign, him or her up for an afternoon of pure fun,
                  laughter and leisure at Bernie's tiger bar, where we work, rest and play all through out the day</p>

              <img id ="left_column_img" src="jpg/tieger.jpg" alt="kids club"/>
              <a href="" title="click me">more info</a>
          </div>

          <div id="right_col_content">

              <h2 class="top_title">Play and Learn</h2>
              <h3 class="top_title" >Activities for all</h3>
              <p>Life is all about balance, and as we spend time feeding our minds, it is also important that we make
                  time for play.Our aim is to make learning not only fun, but a foundation were we can build and grow.
              </p>

              <img id ="right_column_img" src="jpg/Where-Children-Learn-Play-and-Grow.jpg" alt="play and learn"/>
              <a href="" title="click me">more info</a>


          </div>
          <div id="newsflash">
              <h2>Latest news</h2>
              <p>Summer camp 2016 - The amazon, with a touch of carribean, Parents and siblings welcome, more info to come</p>
          </div>

          <div id="left_right_content"><h2 id="activity">What's On Today</h2>

              <img id="jumeirah" src="jpg/jumeirah-beach.jpg" alt="jumeirah"/>
              <img id="artandcraft" src="jpg/artandcraft.jpg" alt="artandcraft"/>

          </div>
          <div id="footer"></div>
     </div>


    </body>

          </html>
```

```css
body{
    background-color: #024378;
}
#wrapper{
 min-width:960px;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #e3f1f2;
}

#header,#img_header{
    min-width: 960px;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100px;
    height:12.5%;
}


.top_title{
    color: #009fc0;
}
nav{
    min-width:640px;
    width: 70%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;
 }

nav ul {
 background: #009fc0;
 padding: 0 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-table;
}
nav ul:after {
  content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
 }
nav ul li {
 float: left;
}


nav ul li:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
 }
nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #96a4a5;
  }

nav ul li a {
 display: block;
    padding: 25px 40px;
 color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul ul li {
    float: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul ul li a {
    padding: 15px 40px;
  }
nav ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #ffffff;
}
nav ul ul ul {
 position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}


nav ul ul {
 background: #ffffff; border-radius: 0; padding: 0;
 position: absolute; top: 100%;display:none;
}

/*images or divs that span across the page use margin left and right 'auto', divs that are smaller in size and form
columns within the page use set margins, i.e10px*/

#img_banner {
    min-width:940px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 240px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#banner{
    min-width: 940px;
    width: 73.4375%;
    height: 240px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#left_col_content{
 float:left;
    min-width: 420px;
    width:32.8125%;
    margin: 1%;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 color: #06acef;
 text-indent:10px;
    padding: 2%;
 }

#right_col_content{
    float:left;
    min-width: 420px;
    width:32.8125%;
    margin: 1%;
 background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #06acef;
 text-indent:10px;
    padding: 2%;
 }

#left_column_img, #right_column_img{
    min-width: 200px;
    width:15.625%;
    min-height: 100px;
    height:12.5%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 }

#newsflash{
 clear:both;
    min-width: 920px;
    width:71.875%;
 min-height:50px;
    height:6.25%;
 background-color: #009fc0;
 margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 color:#fff;
 text-indent:10px;
    padding: 1%;
}


#left_right_content{
    min-width: 890px;
    width: 69.53%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    height:300px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 color: #06acef;
    border: dashed #009fc0;
    padding: 2%;
 }


#activity {
    border-bottom: dotted 3px #06acef;
}
#jumeirah{
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    min-width:80px;
    width: 47%;
    padding: 10px;
}

#artandcraft{
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    min-width:80px;
    width: 47%;
    padding: 10px;
}
#footer{
 clear:both;
    min-width: 940px;
    width:73.4375%;
    min-height:50px;
    height:6.25%;
 background-color: #009fc0;
 margin:auto;
    color:#fff;
 text-indent:10px;
}



@media only screen and (min-width:0px) and (max-width:480px) {

    /*low end windows phone*/

}
@media only screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:640px){

        /*iphone*/
        #header,#img_header{
          width: 50%;
        }
        #left_col_content {
      width: 58%;
        }

        #right_col_content{
          clear: both;
      width: 58%;
        }
#newsflash{
  width: 56%;
}
#left_right_content{
  width: 58%;
}
    }
@media only screen and (min-width:641px) and (max-width:768px) {

    /*high windows phone*/

}
@media only screen and (min-width:769px) and (max-width:1024px) {

    /*ipad*/
    #left_col_content {
 width: 94%;
    }

    #right_col_content{
 width: 94%;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Although it won't solve this, Chrome has a native device screen emulator which might help, just press F12 then CTRL-SHIFT-M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always helpful to place your code on http://jsfiddle.net to help us visualise.

I've copied your code to https://jsfiddle.net/uhds3eac/

The many `min-width`properties you're using should be wrapped in a media-query for only **larger** screen sizes :

```
@media screen and (min-width:920px){
  #newsflash {
    min-width: 920px;
  }
}
```

It's often a good idea to start with mobile, then accomodate for larger screens with `@media` rules.

Note: This isn't the issue but you're missing a starting `<html>` tag

Comment: More helpful and succinct answer than mine, nice one +1

Comment: Here's the same jsfiddle with the `min-width` properties wrapped in their appropriate `@media` rules https://jsfiddle.net/yq9q763q/

Answer (score 0):

Your `min-width` statements look like the culprits, try removing them.

You'll still need to tinker with the `width` of some parts to make it look good, but as a rule try to only use percentage values, not `px`.

```css
body {
  background-color: #024378;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #e3f1f2;
}
#header,
#img_header {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: 12.5%;
}
.top_title {
  color: #009fc0;
}
nav {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
nav ul {
  background: #009fc0;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-table;
}
nav ul:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
}
nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #96a4a5;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 25px 40px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
nav ul ul li {
  float: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul ul li a {
  padding: 15px 40px;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
}
nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
nav ul ul {
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  display: none;
}
/*images or divs that span across the page use margin left and right 'auto', divs that are smaller in size and form
columns within the page use set margins, i.e10px*/

#img_banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 240px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#banner {
  width: 73.4375%;
  height: 240px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#left_col_content {
  float: left;
  width: 32.8125%;
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #06acef;
  text-indent: 10px;
  padding: 2%;
}
#right_col_content {
  float: left;
  width: 32.8125%;
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #06acef;
  text-indent: 10px;
  padding: 2%;
}
#left_column_img,
#right_column_img {
  width: 15.625%;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: 12.5%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#newsflash {
  clear: both;
  width: 71.875%;
  min-height: 50px;
  height: 6.25%;
  background-color: #009fc0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: #fff;
  text-indent: 10px;
  padding: 1%;
}
#left_right_content {
  width: 69.53%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #06acef;
  border: dashed #009fc0;
  padding: 2%;
}
#activity {
  border-bottom: dotted 3px #06acef;
}
#jumeirah {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 47%;
  padding: 10px;
}
#artandcraft {
  clear: none;
  float: right;
  width: 47%;
  padding: 10px;
}
#footer {
  clear: both;
  width: 73.4375%;
  min-height: 50px;
  height: 6.25%;
  background-color: #009fc0;
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
  text-indent: 10px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  /*low end windows phone*/
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 640px) {
  /*iphone*/
  #header,
  #img_header {
    width: 50%;
  }
  #left_col_content {
    width: 58%;
  }
  #right_col_content {
    clear: both;
    width: 58%;
  }
  #newsflash {
    width: 56%;
  }
  #left_right_content {
    width: 58%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  /*high windows phone*/
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  /*ipad*/
  #left_col_content {
    width: 94%;
  }
  #right_col_content {
    width: 94%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="descripton" content="kids at play" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="kids, club, play, learn" />
  <meta name="robots" content=index,follow/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
  <base href="http://localhost/Kids Club/Kids_Club.html" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Kids_Club.css" type="text/css" />
  <title>html_5</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
      <img id="img_header" src="jpg/kids_club_header.jpg" alt="kids club" />
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Playgroups</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Under Fives</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Under Tens</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">The Teens</a>
          </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Play & Learn</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Field Trips</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Tutor Groups</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="banner">
      <img id="img_banner" src="jpg/kids.jpg" alt="kids" />
    </div>
    <div id="left_col_content">
      <h2 class="top_title">Bring out the tiger in you</h2>
      <h3 class="top_title">Activities for the Under Fives and Tens</h3>
      <p>Is your little one sporty, and loves the challenge, then why not sign, him or her up for an afternoon of pure fun, laughter and leisure at Bernie's tiger bar, where we work, rest and play all through out the day
      </p>
      <img id="left_column_img" src="jpg/tieger.jpg" alt="kids club" />
      <a href="" title="click me">more info</a>
    </div>
    <div id="right_col_content">
      <h2 class="top_title">Play and Learn</h2>
      <h3 class="top_title">Activities for all</h3>
      <p>Life is all about balance, and as we spend time feeding our minds, it is also important that we make time for play.Our aim is to make learning not only fun, but a foundation were we can build and grow.
      </p>
      <img id="right_column_img" src="jpg/Where-Children-Learn-Play-and-Grow.jpg" alt="play and learn" />
      <a href="" title="click me">more info</a>
    </div>
    <div id="newsflash">
      <h2>Latest news</h2>
      <p>Summer camp 2016 - The amazon, with a touch of carribean, Parents and siblings welcome, more info to come</p>
    </div>
    <div id="left_right_content">
      <h2 id="activity">What's On Today</h2>
      <img id="jumeirah" src="jpg/jumeirah-beach.jpg" alt="jumeirah" />
      <img id="artandcraft" src="jpg/artandcraft.jpg" alt="artandcraft" />
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Try researching [Mobile First Design](http://www.zell-weekeat.com/how-to-write-mobile-first-css/) to learn more.